# How to display the OpenGraph website image on Facebook without having to type WWW in the URL

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, no-www

I set the facebook opengraph tags in my website to display images on facebook when typing my website's url.
The images only display when typing the www.mywebsite.com , how do i display them when typing mywebsite.com like for times.com and many other websites

```
<meta name="twitter:card" value="summary"> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="766935150367487" />
<meta property="og:title" content="This is your car" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://carhub.fun" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://carhub.fun/images/car15.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Liked it? Click Here for More Info."/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="carhub.fun - Which one are you?"/>
```

Actual result: My website's image thumbnail displays when typing www.mywebsite.com, 
Expected result: to display the image when only typing mywebsite.com like many other famous websites like times.com

Comment: Looks like it is working for me https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcarhub.fun

Comment: hey, it doesnt work when typed on a comment, or timeline without the www, try it